# Derivative of Quadratic Form

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms

For the Quadratic Form $X^TAX; X\in\mathbb{R}^n, A\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ (which simplifies to $\Sigma_{i=0}^n\Sigma_{j=0}^nA_{ij}x_ix_j$), I tried to take the derivative wrt. X ($\Delta_X X^TAX$) and ended up with the following:

The $k^{th}$ element of the derivative represented as

$\Delta_{X_k}X^TAX=[\Sigma_{i=1}^n(A_{ik}x_k+A_{ki})x_i] + A_{kk}x_k(1-x_k)$

Does this result look right? Is there an alternative form?

I'm trying to get to the $\mu_0$ of Gaussian Discriminant Analysis by maximizing the log likelihood and I need to take the derivative of a Quadratic form. Either the result I mentioned above is wrong (shouldn't be because I went over my arithmetic several times) or the form I arrived at above is not the terribly useful to my problem (because I'm unable to proceed).

I can give more details about the problem or the steps I put down to arrive at the above result, but I didn't want to clutter to start off. Please let me know if more details are necessary.

Any link to related material is also much appreciated.

Answer (score 68):

Let $Q(x) = x^T A x$. Then expanding $Q(x+h)-Q(x)$ and dropping the higher order term, we get $DQ(x)(h) = x^TAh+h^TAx = x^TAh+x^TA^Th = x^T(A+A^T)h$, or more typically, $\frac{\partial Q(x)}{\partial x} = x^T(A+A^T)$.

Notice that the derivative with respect to a **column** vector is a **row** vector!

Comment: Could you comment on the difference expansion, please?

Comment: What do you mean? Just compute $Q(x+h)-Q(x)$ explicitly. The only term missing above is $h^T A h$, and we have $|h^T A h| \le \|A\| \|h \|^2$, so the term is $O(\|h\|^2)$.

Comment: Can't see how $(x+h)^T A (x+h)$ would be obvious; I was hoping avoid opening the matrix. Any hint?

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking. Computing the derivative is much like computing the derivative of $x \mapsto x^2$ from first principles. I don't understand what you mean by 'opening the matrix'.

Comment: I don't see how I can expand $(x+h)^T A (x+h)$ so trivially. I mean literally, why $(x+h)^T A (x+h) = x^T A x + h^TAx+x^TAh + h^T A h$ and how can you see that so quickly.  It just looks a messy summation for me.

Comment: There is no need to explicitly compute the sums. Matrix multiplication is associative and distributive, so we can treat them like 'numbers' in this regard. We have $A(x+h) = Ax + Ah$,  $(x+h)^TA = (x^T +h^T) A = x^TA + h^T A$, etc.

Comment: How did you get $x^TA^Th$ from $h^TAx$?

Comment: In general, $(AB)^T=B^T A^T$.

Comment: And for a scalar $x^T = x$.

Comment: @copper.hat: thanks!

Comment: "the derivative with respect to a column vector is a row vector!"

--this is of course assuming you're using [numerator layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions)

Comment: @YiboYang: I think the above notation is fairly standard, I believe.

Comment: @copper.hat, thank you for your answers all of math stack exchange - I have used many of them.  Now, I am wondering, how can you say that $\vert h^TAh \vert \le \vert\vert A \vert\vert \vert\vert h \vert\vert^2$ ?  Is it somehow related to Cauchy Schwarz?  I tried to derive it from Cauchy Schwarz but was unable to, because the L2-norm of a matrix is the largest singular value, and this threw me off a bit.  Thanks again for your answers on stackexchange.            Furthermore, how is the fact the it is of order $\vert h \vert^2$ enough to justify removing it?

Comment: @Sother: Cauchy Schwarz gives $|\langle h, Ah \rangle | \le \|h\| \|Ah\|$ and (if we use the Euclidean norm) we have $\|Ah\| \le \|A\| \|h\|$.

Comment: Thanks.  also, I do not know if you saw my additional question - I editted it later.   how is the fact the it is of order $\vert h \vert^2$ enough to justify removing it?

Comment: Also, what you are referring to when you say $\vert\vert A h \vert\vert \le \vert\vert A \vert\vert \, \vert\vert h\vert\vert$, you actually do not need it to be the Euclidea norm.  *Holder's Inequality* allows that property to hold true for **any** norm!  I just did not know that you could mix matrices and vectors when using Cauchy Schwarz, such as we have done here with matrix $A$ and vector $h$.

Comment: @Sother: The expression $\|Ax\| \le \|A\| \|x\|$ works for induced norms. However, it is irrelevant here in that it is always the case that $\|Ax\| \le K \|x\|$ for some $K$.

Comment: What is $K$ ?  Is it a member of the set of real numbers?  What set is it a member of?

Comment: It is a real constant. If the norm is induced it would be the norm of A.

Comment: I just learned a new trick when your independent variable is in more than two places within your formula: introduce a new (fake) parameter which will then disappear:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} y^TAx = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}[Ax]^T+y^TA $$
The transpose was to make the vector a row vector. Nothing deep there!

Now, if $y=x$ then 
$$ \frac{d}{dx} x^TAx = x^TA^T+x^TA = x^T(A+A^T) \ . $$

Comment: @copper.hat Could you please elaborate on how $\frac{x^T(A + A^T)h}{h} = x^T(A + A^T)$? I understand we are canceling common terms ($h$) from the numerator and the denominator, however, what rules dictate such an operation to be legal in the general case?

Comment: @AnkurRoyChowdhury: I don't understand your question. $h$ is a vector, you can't divide by $h$. I didn't divide by $h$ anywhere. Note that the map $DQ(x)$ is a map $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, which can be represented by a matrix ${\partial Q(x) \over \partial x}$. In other words, $DQ(x)h = {\partial Q(x) \over \partial x}h$.

Comment: Why $||Ax|| \le ||A|| ||x||$ is true? Or since $||Ax||$ is finite, then $||Ax|| \le K||x||$ for some $K \ge 0$.Thus why smallest $K$ is $||A||$(I guess $||A||$ is smallest $K$)?

Comment: The stated solution is for numerator notation of vectors, but it seems arbitrary. How would one find the solution using denominator notation (derivative wrt a column vector is a column vector)? In that case would it be that $h^T DQ(x) = h^T \frac{\partial Q(x)}{\partial x}$ ?

Answer (score 14):

You could also take the derivative of the scalar sum.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
{\bf x^TAx} = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}x_j\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_iA_{ji}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The derivative with respect to the $k$-th variable is then(product rule):
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d {\bf  x^TAx}}{d x_k} & = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\frac{dx_j}{dx_k}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_iA_{ji} + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}x_j\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{dx_i}{dx_k}A_{ji} \\
 & = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_iA_{ki} + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}x_jA_{jk}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

If then you arrange these derivatives into a column vector, you get:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_iA_{1i} + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}x_jA_{j1} \\
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_iA_{2i} + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}x_jA_{j2} \\
\vdots \\ 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_iA_{ni} + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}x_jA_{jn} \\
\end{bmatrix} = {\bf Ax} + ({\bf x}^T{\bf A})^T = ({\bf A} + {\bf A}^T){\bf x}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

or if you choose to arrange them in a row, then you get:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_iA_{1i} + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}x_jA_{j1} &
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_iA_{2i} + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}x_jA_{j2} &
\dots &
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_iA_{ni} + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}x_jA_{jn} 
\end{bmatrix} \\ = ({\bf Ax} + ({\bf x}^T{\bf A})^T)^T = (({\bf A} + {\bf A}^T){\bf x})^T = {\bf x}^T({\bf A} + {\bf A}^T)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

---

Answer (score 6):

It is easier using index notation with Einstein (repeated sum on dummy indices) rule. That is, we can write the $i$th component of $Ax$ as $a_{ij} x_j$, and $x^T A x=x_i a_{ij} x_j
= a_{ij} x_i x_j$. Then take the derivative of $f(\bf{x})$ with respect to a component $x_k$. We find
\begin{eqnarray}
   \partial f/\partial x_k = f,_k = a_{ij} x_{i,k} x_j + a_{ij} x_i x_{j,k} = a_{ij} \delta_{ik} x_j + a_{ij} x_i \delta_{jk} = a_{kj} x_j + a_{ik} x_i, 
\end{eqnarray}
which in matrix notation is $k$th component of ${\bf{x}}^T  A + {\bf{x}}^T A^T$.

Answer (score 6):

Yet another approach using the Frobenius product notation.

For a column vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$  we can write:

$$ x^TAx = Tr(x^TAx) = x:Ax$$

Then we take the differential and derivative as

\begin{align}
    d(x:Ax) & = dx:Ax + x:Adx\\
            & = Ax:dx + A^Tx:dx\\
            & = (Ax + A^Tx):dx\\
         \frac{\partial (x^TAx)}{\partial x} &= (Ax + A^Tx) = (A + A^T)x 
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

I just learned a new trick when your independent variable is in more than two places within your formula: introduce a new (fake) parameter which will then disappear:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} y^TAx = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}[Ax]^T+y^TA $$
The transpose was to make the vector a row vector. Nothing deep there!

Now, if $y=x$ then 
$$ \frac{d}{dx} x^TAx = x^TA^T+x^TA = x^T(A+A^T) \ . $$