# Why do we assume that a matrix in quadratic form is symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

I am looking to the [review document for linear algebra (Zico Kolter (updated by Chuong Do), *Linear Algebra Review and Reference*)](http://cs229.stanford.edu/section/cs229-linalg.pdf), and the part of the quadratic form  (pg17) mentions about an assumption of being symmetric for a matrix in quadratic form. It also includes some declarative equality for that proposed argument.

> What is the practical reason to assume that the matrix describing a quadratic form (over $\mathbb{R}$) is symmetric? I also do not get the idea proposed by the argument? Can someone light me about?

Comment: The argument shows that if $A$ were not symmetric, you could replace it with its symmetric part $\frac12(A+A^T)$ and the quadratic form $x^TAx$ would not change.

Comment: what does "symmetric part" mean?

Comment: You can write any matrix $A$ as the sum of a symmetric matrix and an antisymmetric matrix. Let's call them $B$ and $C$, where $B$ is symmetric and $C$ is antisymmetric. Then it turns out that $B$ is actually equal to $\frac12(A+A^T)$, and $C$ is $\frac12(A-A^T)$. These are called the symmetric and antisymmetric parts of the matrix $A$. **Exercise:** Verify that $B=B^T$ and $C=-C^T$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1964244/339790)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Any matrix A can be written as sum of $(A+A^{T})/2$ and $(A-A^{T})/2$. You can verify that the quadratic form of second term (i.e; $x^{T}(A-A^{T})x$) turns out to be zero (*Try to evaluate the second term and check for yourself*).

Hence, we can assume that we begin with a symmetric matrix. If not, it is anyway possible to convert to an equivalent quadratic form with a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 14):

We can show that the Matrix $\bf{W}$ of the quadratic form $x^T {\bf{W}} x$ can be assumed to be symmetric in the following way:

In general a matrix can be decomposed into a symmetric and an anti-symmetric part as follows:

$$M = \frac{1}{2} ( {\bf{M}} + {\bf{M}}^\top) + \frac{1}{2} ({\bf{M}} - {\bf{M}}^\top) = M_s + M_a$$

Further we note that the symmetric part is invariant to the transpose,
$$ {\bf{M}}_s^\top = {\bf{M}}_s $$
while the antisymmetric part changes its sign under transposition:
$$ {\bf{M}}_a^\top = - {\bf{M}}_a$$

Let us examine the quadratic form of a purely antisymmetric matrix:
$$q = {\bf x}^\top {\bf M}_a {\bf x} = ({{\bf x}^\top {\bf M}_a^\top {\bf x}})^\top  = -({\bf x}^\top {\bf M}_a {\bf x})^\top = -q$$
Which implies that $q=0$ has to hold true.

Now for a general Matrix $\bf W$ we can see that:
$${\bf x}^\top {\bf M} {\bf x} = {\bf x}^\top ({\bf M}_s + {\bf M}_a){\bf x} = {\bf x}^\top {\bf M}_s {\bf x} + {\bf x}^\top {\bf M}_a {\bf x}$$
As we know that $${\bf x}^\top {\bf M}_a {\bf x} = 0$$ we finally find
$${\bf x}^\top {\bf M} {\bf x} = {\bf x}^\top {\bf M}_s {\bf x}$$

Answer (score 6):

The main reason for getting the matrix of a real quadratic form symmetric by replacing the original matrix with its symmetric part ${A+A^T}\over 2$ is that any symmetric matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable and all eigenvalues are real. Then for symmetric $A$ you have some orthogonal matrix $U$ (that is, $U^T=U^{-1}$) and $U^T A U=D$ is real diagonal, and $x^T A x=(Ux)^T(UAU^T)(Ux)=(Ux)^TD(Ux)$ is a sum of squares with real coefficients where the length $\Vert x \Vert$ of the vector $x$ is the same as the length $\Vert Ux\Vert$ of the vector $Ux$.