# Why do positive definite matrices have to be symmetric?

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Definitions of positive definiteness usually look like this:

> A symmetric matrix $M$ is positive definite if $x^T M x > 0$ for all vectors $x \neq 0$.

Why must $M$ be symmetric? The definition seems to make sense for general square matrices.

Comment: Mostly because you get the same quadratic form if you replace $M$ by its symmetric part $(M+M^T) / 2.$ Put another way, the quadratic form remains the same if we subtract off the anti-symmetric part  $(M-M^T) / 2.$

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Let quadratic form $f$ be defined by

$$f (\mathrm x) := \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x$$

where $\mathrm A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Since $\mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x$ is a *scalar*, then $\left(\mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x\right)^\top = \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x$, i.e., $\mathrm x^\top \mathrm A^\top \mathrm x = \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x$. Hence,

$$\mathrm x^\top \left(\frac{\mathrm A - \mathrm A^\top}{2}\right) \mathrm x = 0$$

Thus, the **skew-symmetric** part of matrix $\mathrm A$ does not contribute anything to the quadratic form. What is left is, then, the **symmetric** part

$$\frac{\mathrm A + \mathrm A^\top}{2}$$

which is *diagonalizable* and has *real* eigenvalues and orthogonal eigenvectors, all nice properties.

---

#### Addendum

Taking *affine* combinations of $\mathrm A$ and $\mathrm A^\top$, we obtain

$$\mathrm x^\top \left( \gamma \mathrm A + (1-\gamma) \mathrm A^\top \right) \mathrm x = f (\mathrm x)$$

which yields $f$ for all $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$. Choosing $\gamma = \frac{1}{2}$, we obtain the symmetric part of $\mathrm A$.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!

Comment: Note: the phrases `symmetric "part"` or `skew-symmetric "part"` each refer to an addend in the Toeplitz decomposition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Decomposition_into_symmetric_and_skew-symmetric

Answer (score 10):

Positive definite matrices do not have to be symmetric it is just rather common to add this restriction for examples and worksheet questions.

Though this restriction may seem a little severe, there are a number 
of important applications, which include some classes of partial differential equations and some classes of least squares problems. The advantage of this restriction is that the number of 
operations to do Gaussian elimination can be cut in half.

You might find this previous question regarding non-symmetric positive definite matrices worthwhile reading: [Does non-symmetric positive definite matrix have positive eigenvalues?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83134/does-non-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-have-positive-eigenvalues)