# Lagrange multipliers on matrix function, where matrix doesn't have to be symmetric

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lagrange-multiplier, qcqp

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times1 }, A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. We are looking for maximal and minimal value of $f(x) = x^TAx$ with constraint $g(x)=x^Tx$. We get that $\nabla g= 2x, \nabla f = Ax + A^Tx$ so we have to solve a system
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}(A+A^T)x = 2\lambda x \\
x^Tx = 1  \end{array} \right.$$

If $A$ was symmetric then we would get eigenvectors, but what with this more general case?

Comment: The general case does not matter at all, because only the symmetric part of $A$ contributes to the quadratic form. Hence, you should assume $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why only the symmetric part of $A$ contribute to the quadratic form?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1964244/339790). Note that $$\begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\end{bmatrix} = - x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_1 = 0$$

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you.