# Positive definiteness of $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ and positive eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Given a (non-symmetric) matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, is it possible to relate the sign of its eigenvalues (only the real part) to the definiteness of the corresponding symmetric matrix

$$\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)?$$

I am very confused due to the non-consistent definitions of positive definiteness of matrices across the literature:

- in engineering or applied mathematics textbooks, a general matrix $M$ is positive definite $\iff$ all eigenvalues have positive real parts.
- in classical matrix analysis textbooks, however, the matrix $M$ needs to be Hermitian.

I was wondering if this is kind of justified by the statement above relating the signs of eigenvalues.

Comment: Positive (or negative) definiteness (semi- or not) is almost exclusively used about symmetric real, or Hermitian complex matrices (at least as far as I have seen). And for such matrices, all eigenvalues are real, and you can ask about whether they are all positive or all negative.

Comment: @Arthur And can I relate the sign of the eigenvalues of a non-symmetric $A$ to the definiteness of $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$? E.g. if $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ pos. def, $\Rightarrow Re(\lambda(A))>0$, or viceversa?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1964244/339790).

Comment: If we consider the reals. $x^T A x = x^T A^T x.$ Hence $\frac{1}{2}x^T (A +A^T)x = x^T A x.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample (if I understand the question correctly):

$$A:=\begin{pmatrix}2&2\\-2&-1\end{pmatrix},\qquad \tfrac{1}{2}(A+A^\top)=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{1}{2}i\sqrt7$, yet its symmetric part $\tfrac{1}{2}(A+A^\top)$ is not positive definite.