# Why we don't write the derivative of the Lyapunov function as $\dot V = 2x^TPAx$

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms, stability-in-odes, linear-control, lyapunov-functions

Consider a LTI autonomous system like

$$ \dot x = Ax $$

and the Lyapunov function $V$ is defined as

$$ V(x) = x^T P x $$

where $P>0$. The derivative of $V$ with respect to time is

$$ \frac{d}{dt}V(x) = x^TA^TPx + x^TPAx = x^T \left( A^T P + P A \right) x $$

We have $\frac{d}{dt}V(x)$, a real number, and $x^TA^TPx$ , $x^TPAx$ are also two real numbers, and we know they are transpose to each other. Why don't we write the following instead?

$$\frac{d}{dt}V(x) = x^TPAx + \left(x^TPAx\right)^T = 2 x^T P A x $$

Then, if $PA<0$, we have the Lyapunov stability instead of $PA+A^TP < 0$. It seems maybe stupid but I can't figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: Note that what you differentiate with respect to time is $V \circ x$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I tried if I calculate $\frac{d}{dt}(V) = (dV/dx)(dx/dt) $ and I get same resault. I must get into some trap but I can't figure it out..

Comment: Note that [only the symmetric part](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1964244/339790) of $2 P A$ contributes to the quadratic form. What is this symmetric part?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $2PA$ is not symmetric but $x^TPAx$ is a number, so we have a transpose of this number is also itself which means $a^T = (x^TPAx)^T = x^TA^TPx = a^T = a = x^TPAx$

Comment: Does it make sense to write $PA \prec 0$ when $PA$ is not symmetric?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you so much! I got it. So in this logic$2PA$ should be symmetric to write $2PA < 0$  and if it is not, we take $(PA+A^TP)$ which is symmetric and it is exactly the usual case.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @RodrigodeAzevedo ! The right logic should be like this:

Consider the expression $\frac{d}{dt}V(x) = x^T(A^TP + PA)x = 2x^TPAx$.

The objective is to find $P>0$ such that $\forall x\neq 0, \dot{V}(x) < 0$.

- If the matrix $PA$ is symmetric, the condition $\dot{V}(x) < 0$ is equivalent to $PA < 0$, note that the notion of "negative/positive definite" is applicable only in case of symmetric matrix.
- If not, the condition $\dot{V}(x) < 0$ is equivalent to $A^TP +PA < 0$ (where $A^TP +PA$ is a symmetric matrix).

So we always use the general form $A^TP +PA$ because it is already symmetric regardless of the symmetry of matrix $PA$.