# Non-symmetric positive semi-definiteness in literature

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

The article [Density matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix) on Wikipedia includes the following sentence

> Some authors use more general definitions of definiteness, including some non-symmetric real matrices, or non-Hermitian complex ones.

As I was always taught positive semi-definite matrices are symmetric over real numbers and Hermitian over complex numbers, this seems curious to me. I know that matrices like

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

always produce positive numbers over real vectors. But can you provide me any examples in literature or articles that use the broader definition of positive semi-definiteness?

Comment: some authors, but I have never seen it. In any case, adding a skew symmetric matrix to an existing matrix does not change the quadratic form.  Add $\begin{pmatrix}0 &  -\frac{1}{2}  \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0\end{pmatrix}$  to yours

Comment: Quoting [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83134/does-non-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-have-positive-eigenvalues#comment196257_83134): *"Positive-definite should not be a term that applies to matrices. It should only apply to quadratic forms, which are naturally described by symmetric matrices only"*

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1964039/339790)