# What are the bounds on $x^TAx$ when the matrix $A$ has complex eigenvalues with positive real parts?

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

We all are familiar with the fact that

$$ \lambda_{\min}(A)\|x\|^2 \leq x^TAx \leq \lambda_{\max}(A)\|x\|^2 $$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ happens to be a positive definite matrix. But what will be the equivalent identity when $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a matrix with complex eigenvalues where the real part is positive? What will be the upper and lower bound in that case?

Comment: You need to look at the eigenvalues of ${1 \over 2} (A+A^T)$.

Comment: Hi! I didnt get it, $\frac{A+A^T}{2}$ will be a symmetric matrix. But I was interested in $x^TAx$.

Comment: Note that $x^T A x = {1\over 2} x^T(A+A^T)x$. So $\lambda_\min({1 \over 2}(A+A^T)) \|x\|^2 \le x^T A x \le \lambda_\max({1 \over 2}(A+A^T)) \|x\|^2$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307381/339790)

Answer (score 1):

The theorem you stated is $Rayleigh-Ritz$ theorem which is valid for Hermitian matrices(if $A=A^H$.) So in general for any matrix $A$ - it can be written as $A = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^H) + \frac{1}{2}(A-A^H).$ Substitute this A back in $x^HAx \to$ this is equivalent to $\frac{1}{2}x^H(A+A^H)x$. Now you can bound the eigen values of this $A'$ hermitian matrix.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}x^H(A-A^H)x$ would always be $0$.

Comment: Hi siddhant! Will it work even when $A$ happens to be in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$? My $A$ matrix is real.

Comment: My matrix is something like $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 &0 &0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: It is not true that the eigenvalues of ${1 \over 2}(A+A^*)$ are $2 \operatorname{re} \lambda_A$.

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat ! my mistake. We can estimate the eigen for $A'$ only whatever they may be.

Comment: @Siddhant Your claim is not true for complex matrices, since $x^H A^H x = (x^H A x)^H = \overline{x^H A x} \neq x^H A x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{2}(A + A^H) = \frac{1}{4}\left((A+I)^H(A+I) - (A-I)^H(A-I) \right)$$

$$\frac{-i}{2}(A - A^H) = \frac{1}{4}\left((A+iI)^H(A+iI) - (A-iI)^H(A-iI) \right)$$

Some useful decompositions aiding the other answer.

Comment: They are not the tightest bounds! Counter example: $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 10 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Its numerical radius (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range) is ~8.57 but its norm is ~10. There is no vector $x$ exists such that $x^T A x = s_\max(A)$. You can only say that there is a vector such that $\lVert A x \rVert = s_\max(A)$.

Comment: @obareey i have updated my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: But $(B_1 + i B_2)^H = B_1 - i B_2$, so $B_1 + i B_2$ is not Hermitian.