# Do all symmetric matrices represent a quadratic form?

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices, hermitian-matrices

If a quadratic form is represented as a matrix, it may not be symmetric, but there must exist a representation that is symmetric (or Hermitian if complex). But is the reverse true? That is, do all symmetric and Hermitian matrices represent a quadratic form (except maybe in the case where matrices are all zeros)?

Comment: For a symmetric matrix $A$, consider the map $x\mapsto x^T Ax$ (in the real case). What are the properties that it needs to satisfy to be a quadratic form? Can you check them?

Comment: $A$ represents a quadriatic form if $x^TAx = x^TBx$ where $B$ is unique and where $B=\frac{A +A^T}{2}$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly but note that since $A$ is symmetric we have $A + A^T = 2A$.

Comment: What you wrote is true. [Any quadratic form can be represented by a symmetric matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307381/949989). The reverse is trivially true. The form that is identically zero is a quadratic form. Perhaps some prefer to call it degenerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking, for a field $F$ with $char F\ne 2$, there is a correspondence between symmetric bilinear forms and quadratic forms (Proposition 1.6 in [Pfister's Book](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Albrecht-Pfister-ebook/dp/B01DM27ZA0/ref=sr_1_1?crid=LMO2X23JU8BC&keywords=Pfister+quadratic+form&qid=1703782078&sprefix=pfister+quadratic+for%2Caps%2C261&sr=8-1)). So, the answer for your question is "yes" for real/complex symmetric matrices.

For a more detailed exposition on quadratic forms over fields (and a proof of the above cited Proposition) I recommend [Introduction To Quadratic Forms Over Fields](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/T-Y-Lam/dp/0821810952/ref=sr_1_2?crid=EPCJ1DI789E3&keywords=T+Y+Lam&qid=1703782015&sprefix=ty+la%2Caps%2C332&sr=8-2) or [Quadratic Forms with Applications to Algebraic Geometry and Topology](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Albrecht-Pfister-ebook/dp/B01DM27ZA0/ref=sr_1_1?crid=LMO2X23JU8BC&keywords=Pfister+quadratic+form&qid=1703782078&sprefix=pfister+quadratic+for%2Caps%2C261&sr=8-1).

Comment: Ok so, for char ≠ 2
1. every matrix has an associated bilinear form
2. every symmetric matrix has an associated bilinear form
3. every symmetric bilinear form has an associated quadratic form