# What is the derivative of the function involving inner product $f(x)=\langle Ax,Bx\rangle$

Tags: analysis

I want to find the first and second derivative of $f(x)=\langle Ax,Bx\rangle$, where $\langle\,,\rangle$ is the inner product, A and B are $n\times n$ matrices and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. 
Here's my thoughts:
Since A and B are linear transformations, their derivatives are themselves. So maybe we can treat f as a function from $\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0):

As the inner product is defined by $\langle u, v\rangle = u^Tv$ we can reformulate your function to $f(x) = (Ax)^TBx = x^TA^TBx$

As seen here: [Differentiate $f(x)=x^TAx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312077/differentiate-fx-xtax) you get the derivative
$$f'(x) = 2x^TA^TB$$
Calculating the next derivative should be much easier now.

Comment: $A^TB$ is not necessarily symmetric.

Comment: Oh you're right, I oversaw that. I didn't find a formula for the derivative of $x^TAx$ to the fast, but I'm sure there is one