# Hessian of a quadratic function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix, scalar-fields

> Assume that the quadratic function $f : {\Bbb R}^n \to {\Bbb R}$ is given by $$ f(x) = \frac12 x^T P x + q^T x + r$$ Calculate the Hessian of $f$.

---

Actually, I don't know how to apply Hessian on $f$ because Hessian requires 2nd order differentials and I don't know how to apply 2nd order differential on $f$.

Comment: $x^T=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$. Expand $x^TPx$ as a sum of terms $p_{ij}x_i x_j$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/239207/339790)

Answer (score 0):

Calculate partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$, put them in a matrix, this is the Hessian.

$$
\nabla^2 f(x) = \frac12(P+P^T)
$$