# Derivative of chi-squared function w.r.t. parameter vector

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, chi-squared

I'm trying to derive the derivative of the chi-squared function w.r.t. the parameter vector $p$.

With $\chi^2$ being:

$\chi^2(p) = \sum \left[ \frac{y(t_i) - \hat{y}(ti_i; p)}{\sigma_{y_i}} \right]^2$

with $y$ being a 1xn vector, $\hat{y}$ being 1xn and $\sigma$ being a nxn symmetric matrix. In vector notation:

$$ 
(y - \hat{y}(p))^TW(y-\hat{y}(p)) \\
= y^TWy - 2y^TW\hat{y} + \hat{y}^TW\hat{y}
$$
with $W = 1/\sigma^2_{yi}$. 
I dropped the dependence of $\hat{y}$ on $p$ on the second line for simplicity.

What i get is this:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}}\chi^2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial{p}} \left( y^TWy - 2y^TW\hat{y} + \hat{y}^TW\hat{y} \right) \\
= -2y^TW + \hat{y}^T(W + W^T) \\
= -2(y-\hat{y})^TW
$$

However according to [this](http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/ce281/lm.pdf) the solution should be:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}}\chi^2 = 2(y-\hat{y})^TW \frac{\partial}{\partial{p}} (y-\hat{y}) \\
= -2(y-\hat{y})^TW \left[ \frac{\partial{\hat{y}}}{\partial{p}}\right] \\
= -2(y-\hat{y})^TWJ
$$

where $J$ is the Jacobian. So somehow i seem to be missing the jacobian $J$ in my derivation. Can someone explain why?

Comment: There seem to be a few problems, most of which seem to be because you are forgetting to use the chain rule. Y hat depends on p! And also y is constant (with respect to p), so its derivative is zero.

Comment: Try writing it out in coordinates

Comment: @AreaMan , how so?

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}}\chi^2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial{p}} (y^TWy) - \frac{\partial}{\partial{p}} (2y^TW\hat{y}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial{p}} (\hat{y}^TW\hat{y}) \\
= -2y^TW + \hat{y}^T(W + W^T) \\
= -2(y-\hat{y})^TW
$$

the first term drops since it's a constant, $2y^TW$ is a constant so $\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}}(2y^TW\hat{y}) = 2y^TW $ no? and the derivative of the last term $\hat{y}^TW\hat{y}$ is $\hat{y}^T(W + W^T)$; just like the [derivative of the quadratic form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189434/derivative-of-quadratic-form)

Comment: What's the derivative of $ 2 y f(p)$? With respect to p. (The one dimensional case of the quadratic form. Here f is y hat.) You need the chain rule, or similar.

Comment: I see.. Thanks!