# Gradient of a matrix expression

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms

What would be $\nabla f(x)$ if $f(x) = x^tAx$ where A is a n by n matrix and x is a n by 1 matrix. I have gone till $x'Ax + x^tAx'$ (where x' represents derivative) to find the solution but can see how I can write this as $(A^t + A)x$?

Comment: If you're trying to find the derivative of a scalar with respect to a vector, the derivative must be a vector. So the expression you've arrived at is not correct, since it is a scalar.

Comment: I just tried to apply the simple chain rule. Can you help me get to the right expression?

Answer (score 3):

Before we start deriving the gradient, some facts and notations for brevity:

- Trace and Frobenius product relation $$\left\langle A, B C\right\rangle={\rm tr}(A^TBC) := A : B C$$
- Cyclic properties of Trace/Frobenius product 
  \begin{align}
  A : B C 
   &= BC : A \\
   &= A C^T   :  B  \\
   &= {\text{etc.}} \cr
  \end{align}

Let $f(x) := x^T A x = x:Ax$.

Now, we can obtain the differential first, and then the gradient.
\begin{align}
df  
&= d\left( x:Ax \right) \\
&= \left(dx : Ax\right)  + \left(x : A \ dx\right) \\
&= \left(Ax : dx\right)  + \left(A^Tx : dx\right) \\
&= \left( A + A^T\right)x : dx\\
\end{align}

Thus, the gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x) =  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left\{x^T A x\right\} = \left( A + A^T\right)x.
\end{align}

Comment: can you help figure it out using summations because I am not aware of frobenius norm properties? or some other method that would be recommended for beginners.

Comment: see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189434/derivative-of-quadratic-form

Comment: Thanks man. The explanation by Copper.hat on that really helped!
@MISC {189436,
    TITLE = {Derivative of Quadratic Form},
    AUTHOR = {copper.hat (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/27978/copper-hat)},
    HOWPUBLISHED = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
    NOTE = {URL:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/189436 (version: 2015-07-18)},
    EPRINT = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/189436},
    URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/189436}
}