# Discrepancy in derivative of quadratic form

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, quadratic-forms

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric and $x,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I would like to compute $\nabla f$ where
$$f = \frac{1}{2}x^T A x - x^Tb + c.$$
Now my issue is in how the derivative is calculated. I have seen
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} x^TAx = x^T(A+A^T)$$
and also
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} x^TAx = (A+A^T)x$$
which one is correct? In my readings I more frequently see this derivative as $x^T(A+A^T)$ however I also see that $\nabla f = Ax - b$ (for example, [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent)), but the first definition does not imply the expression for $\nabla f$ (shouldn't we have $\nabla f = x^TA - b$)?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that these two expressions are the transpose of each other, and since A is symmetric the transpose of the left hand side is itself

Comment: @Aphyd Which left hand side?

Comment: x^T A x. But now I've forgotten if transpose and derivatives commute

Comment: @Aphyd In terms of dimensions, since $x^TA$ is $1 \times n$ how can it be the same as $Ax$ (which has dimension $n \times 1$) unless they are row/column representations of one another.

Comment: Good point. To be honest in my classes my professors always just explain derivatives with respect to vectors as "just temporarily pretend the vector is a number and differentiate as usual" which has always been annoying and not very satisfactory. Hopefully someone who knows more than me about this will come along.

Comment: The last of your three displays is the derivative of $x^T A x$ with respect to $x^T$, not with respect to $x$. See e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/189434).

Comment: (Assuming [numerator layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions), anyway. In column layout it's the opposite.)

Comment: @prets Ah that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no correct or incorrect computations, there are mostly conventions.
You may arrange your partial derivatives in a column or a row vector.
The important thing is that you must stick to yourconvention all along the way: this choice will impose a certain structure on the chain rule for instance.
The Wikipedia page [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) is the place to learn more on the two options.