# How to calculate $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}v^{T}Mv}{\mathrm{d}v} $, where $v$ is a vector and $M$ is a matrix?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

I tried applying the product rule, but I do not know how to calculate each derivative. Which formula do I need to use here?

Comment: Many useful related answers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189434/derivative-of-quadratic-form

Comment: See many useful identities for derivatives of vector and matrix functions at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Comment: @AlexS I must have searched all the wrong keywords on Wikipedia when I needed this (or it didn't exist at the time). Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let denote the scalar
$\phi(\mathbf{v})
=\mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{v}
=\mathbf{v}: \mathbf{M} \mathbf{v}$
where the colon operator : denotes the Frobenius inner product.
See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product)

Taking the differential yields

$$
d\phi
=d\mathbf{v}:\mathbf{M} \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{v} : \mathbf{M} d\mathbf{v}
= \left( \mathbf{M}+\mathbf{M}^T \right) \mathbf{v} : d\mathbf{v}
$$
By definition, the LHS term
$\left( \mathbf{M}+\mathbf{M}^T \right) \mathbf{v}$ is the gradient of $\phi$.