# How to caculate the gradient of $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TMx+b^Tx$?

Tags: gradient-descent

A linear complementarity problem(LCP):

$y=Mx+b$

$x_iy_i=0$

$x_i ≥0$, $y_i≥0$

$M=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}0 & -A^T\\A & 0\end{array}\right]$

$x \in R^n$, $y\in R^n$

Problem: $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TMx+b^Tx$, please calculate the gradient $\nabla f(x)$.

My answer: $\nabla f(x) = x^TM+b^T$, right or not?

Comment: You can always expand the indices and sums. Looks correct to me.

Comment: Is $M$ symmetric? You could always looke at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/189436/27978

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your help! M is a positive semidefinite matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the $(i,j)^{\text{th}}$ element of matrix $M$ to be:  $~M_{ij}=m_{ij}$

$$\begin{align}
f&=\frac{1}2 \sum_{i}\sum_{j} x_i m_{ij} x_j+\sum_{i}b_ix_i\\
\\
\partial_k f&=\frac{1}2\sum_{i}\sum_{j} (\partial_k x_i) m_{ij} x_j+\frac{1}2\sum_{i}\sum_{j} x_i m_{ij} (\partial_k x_j)+\sum_{i}b_i(\partial_k x_i)\\
\\
\partial_k f&=\frac{1}2\sum_{i}\sum_{j} (\delta_{ki}) m_{ij} x_j+\frac{1}2\sum_{i}\sum_{j} x_i m_{ij} (\delta_{kj})+\sum_{i}b_i(\delta_{ki})\\
\\
\partial_k f&=\frac{1}2\sum_{j} m_{kj} x_j+\frac{1}2\sum_{i} x_i m_{ik}+b_k\\
\\
\nabla f&=\frac{1}{2}Mx+\frac{1}{2}x^TM+b
\end{align}$$

Write them into row-vector form:

$$\begin{align}
\nabla f&=\frac{1}{2}x^TM^T+\frac{1}{2}x^TM+b^T\\
\\
\nabla f&=x^T\left(\frac{M+M^T}{2}\right)+b^T
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! And $M=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}0 & -A^T\\A & 0\end{array}\right]$ 
 $\therefore M+M^T=0 \Rightarrow \nabla f=b^T$

Comment: Great, glad it helps! If you like my solution, please vote and accept $\checkmark$ my answer :) @YusongLuo

Answer (score 0):

The differential is:
$$
df(x)\cdot h = \frac{1}{2}(x^tMh +h^tMx)+b^th
$$
To get the gradient, express this linear form using the scalar product :
$$
df(x)\cdot h = \frac{1}{2}\langle x,Mh \rangle +\frac{1}{2}\langle  h,Mx\rangle+\langle b,h \rangle = \langle \frac{1}{2}(M + M^t)x+b,h \rangle 
$$
By consequence the gradient $\nabla f$ is the vector :
$$
\nabla f_{|x} = \frac{1}{2}(M + M^t)x+b 
$$
If $M$ is symmetric this reduces to
$$
\nabla f_{|x} = Mx+b 
$$

---

Rational: if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then the differential at $x$, $df(x)$ is a linear form $\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$. But we know (1) that there exists a vector $v$ such that $df(x)\cdot h = \langle v_x, h \rangle$. This vector $v_x$ is by definition the gradient at $x$, denoted by $\nabla f_{|x}$

(1) Riesz representation theorem