# What rules are applied in this matrix derivative?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

Reading the justification for Least Squares Minimization (in Matrix form), I come up with the expression:

$$0=\frac{dS}{d\beta}\left( \hat{\beta}\right)= \frac{d}{d\beta}\left.\left( y^Ty-\beta^T X^Ty-y^TX\beta+\beta^TX^TX\beta \right)\right\rvert_{\beta=\hat{\beta}} = -2X^Ty+ 2X^TX\hat{\beta}$$

I am not sure I follow the rules they apply here, what are the main matrix derivative rules applied in this expression ?

[Wikipedia Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_ordinary_least_squares#Least_squares_estimator_for_.CE.B2)

Comment: This might help https://math.stackexchange.com/a/189436/27978

Comment: Let $f(\beta) = \|X\beta-y\|^2$ and expand using the inner product. Then compute $f(\beta+h)-f(\beta) = (2 \beta^TX^T X - 2 y^TX )h+h^T X^T X h$ and note that the last term is of order $(\|h\|^2)$.

Comment: @copper.hat no idea what you mean

Comment: You might want to review what a matrix derivative means.

Comment: I get that you're adding a tiny matrix h to b, and that would be equivalent to a differential when h goes to 0. But the distributive of the dot product is confusing, you reduced it to a single step @copper.hat

Comment: With the linear operator $L(h) = (2 \beta^TX^T X - 2 y^TX )h$ we see that $f(\beta+h)-f(\beta)-L(h) $ is $o(\|h\|)$, hence $L$ is the derivative.

Comment: so in matrices the derivative $ lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \Delta f / \Delta h$ is rather $lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \Delta f = f_2*\Delta h$ in very broad terms ? @copper.hat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Check out the section "Scalar-by-vector identities"

Comment: this is so useful, thank you

Comment: No problem! That page with all the identities is so helpful lmao

Answer (score 0):

They are of the form $α = x^T A x$, $α = y^T A x$ and what you need is to know how to compute $\frac{\partial α}{\partial x}$ and  $\frac{\partial α}{\partial y}$.

The following referenece has exactly the form of what you want to take the derivative. You can also find how the derivative is proved.

References:
[MatrixCalculus](https://atmos.washington.edu/%7Edennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf)

Proposition 7,8