How to prove $∂(x^TA x)/∂x = 2A$?
I am trying to prove that for a symmetric matrix $A$, the following is true:  $∂(x^TA x)/∂x = 2A$ .

Part 1: First I tried to verify this for a small example:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33}
\end{bmatrix} \quad \text{(symmetric matrix)}
$$
$$
x = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Step 1: Calculate $x^T A x$
First, calculate $Ax$:
$$
Ax = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + a_{13}x_3 \\
a_{12}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + a_{23}x_3 \\
a_{13}x_1 + a_{23}x_2 + a_{33}x_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, multiply $x^T$ by $(Ax)$:
$$
x^T A x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + a_{13}x_3 \\
a_{12}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + a_{23}x_3 \\
a_{13}x_1 + a_{23}x_2 + a_{33}x_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Step 2: Expand $x^T A x$
$$
\begin{align}
x^T A x &= x_1(a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + a_{13}x_3) + x_2(a_{12}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + a_{23}x_3) + x_3(a_{13}x_1 + a_{23}x_2 + a_{33}x_3) \\
&= a_{11}x_1^2 + a_{12}x_1x_2 + a_{13}x_1x_3 + a_{12}x_2x_1 + a_{22}x_2^2 + a_{23}x_2x_3 + a_{13}x_3x_1 + a_{23}x_3x_2 + a_{33}x_3^2
\end{align}
$$
Step 3: Calculate $∂(x^T A x)/∂x$
Find the partial derivative with respect to each $x_i$:
$$
\frac{\partial(x^T A x)}{\partial x} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial(x^T A x)}{\partial x_1} \\
\frac{\partial(x^T A x)}{\partial x_2} \\
\frac{\partial(x^T A x)}{\partial x_3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
calculate each component:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial(x^T A x)}{\partial x_1} &= 2a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + a_{13}x_3 + a_{12}x_2 + a_{13}x_3 \\
&= 2a_{11}x_1 + 2a_{12}x_2 + 2a_{13}x_3 \\
\frac{\partial(x^T A x)}{\partial x_2} &= a_{12}x_1 + a_{12}x_1 + 2a_{22}x_2 + a_{23}x_3 + a_{23}x_3 \\
&= 2a_{12}x_1 + 2a_{22}x_2 + 2a_{23}x_3 \\
\frac{\partial(x^T A x)}{\partial x_3} &= a_{13}x_1 + a_{23}x_2 + a_{13}x_1 + a_{23}x_2 + 2a_{33}x_3 \\
&= 2a_{13}x_1 + 2a_{23}x_2 + 2a_{33}x_3
\end{align}
$$
Step 4: Combine the results
$$
\frac{\partial(x^T A x)}{\partial x} = \begin{bmatrix}
2a_{11}x_1 + 2a_{12}x_2 + 2a_{13}x_3 \\
2a_{12}x_1 + 2a_{22}x_2 + 2a_{23}x_3 \\
2a_{13}x_1 + 2a_{23}x_2 + 2a_{33}x_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Factor out 2
$$
\frac{\partial(x^T A x)}{\partial x} = 2\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + a_{13}x_3 \\
a_{12}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + a_{23}x_3 \\
a_{13}x_1 + a_{23}x_2 + a_{33}x_3
\end{bmatrix} = 2Ax
$$
This produces the desired result:
$$
\frac{\partial(x^T A x)}{\partial x} = 2Ax = 2A\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Part 2: Now, I am trying to prove this in general.
I can recognize that the equivalence between matrix multiplications and summations
$$x^T A x = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x_i a_{ij} x_j$$
$$\frac{\partial (x^T A x)}{\partial x_k} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x_i a_{ij} x_j$$
Using the product rule:
$$\frac{\partial (x^T A x)}{\partial x_k} = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_k} a_{ij} x_j + x_i a_{ij} \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_k}\right)$$
Here is where I got stuck.

I am having trouble manipulating these matrix derivatives to prove this identity. Can someone please help me?

And for non-symmetric matrices: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/189434/42969

Also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222894/how-to-take-the-gradient-of-the-quadratic-form

Use $\partial x_i/\partial x_k = \delta_{ik}$.

If you are working over real-valued matrices, then because $A$ is symmetric, $A=B^\intercal B$ for some matrix $B$, in which case $x^\intercal A x=|Bx|^2$, from which the result follows easily.
